# Cannot reference methods on my JQuery prototype class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm defining the behaviour for my `content_item` elements like this:

```
    $.fn.makeContentItem = function() {

        $(this).selectItem = function() {
            $(".content_item").removeClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass("selected");
            console.log($(this).css('width'));
        }

        $(this).click(function(event) {
            console.log($(this));
            $(this).selectItem();
        });

    }
```

I then apply makeContentItem with:

```
$(".content_item").makeContentItem();
```

Clicking a `content_item` element generates this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'selectItem'
```

Answer (score 1):

You added the method to a jQuery collection, then discarded that jQuery collection. Instead, you should to add it to the elements data structure and reference it from that.

```
$.fn.makeContentItem = function() {

    this.data("selectItem",function() {
        $(".content_item").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        console.log($(this).css('width'));
    });

    this.click(function(event) {
        console.log($(this));
        $(this).data("selectItem").call(this);
    });

}
```

or better yet, just make it a private function.

```
$.fn.makeContentItem = function() {

    var selectItem = function() {
        $(".content_item").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        console.log($(this).css('width'));
    };

    this.click(function(event) {
        console.log($(this));
        selectItem.call(this);
    });

    // and to make it a complete plugin, return this.
    return this;

}
```

Comment: Nice! The private method version looks cleaner.

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/SLZuc/ Oh, you meant the .data version. fixed above, but not fiddling because it's an odd way of doing it anyway.